# how to display dynamic images in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, json, image, react-native

I have to show dynamic images in my app, address of that images coming in `{item.p2[0].image}` this json object as below

```
/media/profiles/qA94ILU.jpg
/media/profiles/DSCN3253.JPG
/media/profiles/DSCN2102_iVPC7S1.JPG
/media/profiles/DSCN3253.JPG
/media/profiles/DSCN2204.JPG
```

and i am trying to display those images as

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://10.42.0.1:8000{item.p2[0].image}'}} style={{width: 150, height: 100}} />
```

and if i displaying it with direct address on chrome or like this way `source={{uri:'http://10.42.0.1:8000/media/profiles/qA94ILU.jpg'}}` then it is displaying correctly. So how should i take that address from json object to any variable and How to display it?

for additional info

tried with these but not working

```
render() {
    contents = this.state.qwerty.data.map((item) => {
        add = item.p2[0].image;
        //console.log(add);
      return (
          <View key={item.p1.id} style={styles.box}>
            <Text>
              {item.p2[0].image}
            </Text>
           <Image source={{uri: 'http://10.42.0.1:8000{item.p2[0].image}'}} style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>

           <Image source={{uri: 'http://10.42.0.1:8000{add}'}}style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>
          </View>
        );
     });
```

Comment: are you want to show all image ?

Comment: @MaulanaPrambadi yes.. want to show all images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax to combine strings. Check [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more info.

Change this

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://10.42.0.1:8000{item.p2[0].image}'}} style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>
```

to this

```
<Image source={{uri: `http://10.42.0.1:8000${item.p2[0].image}`}} style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>
```

or

```
<Image source={{uri: 'http://10.42.0.1:8000' + item.p2[0].image}} style={{ width: 150, height: 100}}/>
```